# Why am I getting this error - searching

Tags: python

I have the following code based on Python School:

**EDIT: fixed the indentation of "position" and "return found", and used "raw_input**

```
def linearSearch(item,my_list):
    found = False
    position = 0
    while position < len(my_list) and not found:
        if my_list(position) == item:
            found = True
        position = position + 1
    return found

bag = ['book','pencil','pen','note book','sharpner','rubber']
item = raw_input('What item do you want to check for in the bag?')
itemFound = linearSearch(item,bag)
if itemFound:
    print('Yes, the item is in the bag')
else:
    print('Your item seems not to be in the bag')
```

When I ran the program, I got the following:

```
What item do you want to check for in the bag?pencil
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 11, in <module>
    item = input('What item do you want to check for in the bag?')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'pencil' is not defined
```

**EDIT: Getting the following error after the edits, although tried to put the item name between quotes**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 12, in <module>
    itemFound = linearSearch(item,bag)
  File "test.py", line 5, in linearSearch
    if my_list(position) == item:
TypeError: 'list' object is not callable
```

Why am I getting this error?

Thanks.

Comment: Is this the whole code?

Comment: When you enter the input wrap it with quotes...`'pencil'`...not only `pencil`

Comment: @IronFist Python 2.7.10

Comment: @IronFist yes, although wrapping the item I'm getting the error you see in the post.

Comment: @Arman yes, this is the whole code

Comment: Python 2.7 and you `print (...)` ? ... should be `print ...` ...not an answer to your question, but as a side note

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`my_list` is a list, index it not call it as a function, so it should be :

```
if my_list[position] == item:
```

Another thing, if you are looking for one particular item in `my_list`, than just return from `linearSearch` as soon as you found it, no need to keep iterating through the rest of `my_list`:

```
if my_list[position] == item:
    found = True
    return found
```

Comment: Thanks for your nice catch. Yes, this solved the issue :-)

Comment: No pblm @Simplicity..;)

Comment: No need for the `found` variable, either. And the iteration through the loop is still faulty (ignoring for now that the iteration is also overly complicated).

Comment: @KonradRudolph .. I don't know what's the OP's intention to write the `linearSearch` function, probably educative, but surely that can all be replace with `if item in bag: print 'Yes....'`

Comment: @IronFist Sure. Hence my saying that we should *ignore* this. But the code, after your corrections, was still broken originally (though now fixed by OP). To clarify: there’s nothing wrong with your answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that you are using python2 and this is python3 code. So it would be best for you to install python3 and this code should run OK. Or in python2 you could you the raw_input function instead of input.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made some edits to the post above based on your reply, but still getting an error. Any ideas why is that? Thanks

Comment: @Simplicity The input function in python2 does the same as eval(raw_input())

Comment: @Simplicity You are trying to call a list as a function! You need to get an item at index, replace this: <i>if my_list(position) == item</i> with this: <i>if my_list[position] == item</i>

Comment: Sorry, ignore the tags, I did not know they do not work in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `input` with `raw_input` to get a string: `input` tells Python 2 to *evaluate* the input string.

That said, your code has more problems: for instance, you increment the `position` in the wrong place.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made some edits to the post above based on your reply, but still getting an error. Any ideas why is that? Thanks

Comment: @Simplicity No, it clearly **doesn’t** work. But as mentioned that’s not the only problem with your code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this some kind of homework, otherwise there is no need to implement this function just do `item in bag`. Anyway about the function, there is no need to keep track of the index like that, use range or xrange for that, or having a variable found, just do `return True` when found and at the end of the function do `return False`

```
def linearSearch(item,my_list):
    for position in xrange(len(my_list)):
        if my_list[position] == item:
            return True
    return False
```

you can also use the fact that a list is iterable and do

```
def linearSearch(item,my_list):
    for elem in my_list:
        if elem == item:
            return True
    return False
```